# How can I connect to MySQL from windows forms?

Tags: c#, mysql, windows, winforms

How can I connect to a MySQL database from Windows Forms?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Numerous sample of connection strings here : http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: thanx dude..it is really superb.im lovin it!!

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Connector from here](http://www.mysql.de/products/connector/).
There's a [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net.html) too.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.functionx.com/mysqlnet/csharp/Lesson02.htm) is a full article on connecting to mysql using [Connector/Net 6.0](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.0.html).

Alternatively you can also use [OleDb to connect to MySql.](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/Database/Database-Programming-in-C-Sharp-with-MySQL-Using-OleDB/)

Answer (score 1):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string MyConString = "SERVER=localhost;" +"DATABASE=mydatabase;" 
        "UID=testuser;" +"PASSWORD=testpassword;";
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
    MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    MySqlDataReader Reader;
    command.CommandText = "select * from mycustomers";
    connection.Open();
    Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (Reader.Read())
    {
        string thisrow = "";                
        for (int i = 0;i<Reader.FieldCount;i++)     
            thisrow += Reader.GetValue(i).ToString() + ","; 
        listBox1.Items.Add(thisrow);
    }
    connection.Close(); 
}
```

i think this gonna be the simple one right!!!
but thanx all of u guys for responding and providing me the documentation!