# Question about Visual Studio and MySQL connectivity

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, xampp

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Where to begin with Card Reader application in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238269/where-to-begin-with-card-reader-application-in-c)
>   [How can I connect to MySQL from windows forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101961/how-can-i-connect-to-mysql-from-windows-forms)

I have installed XAMPP, which includes MySQL version 5.

I need to connect to this database from C#, but when I try to add a data source in Visual Studio it doesn't have a provider for MySQL version 5.

What do I need in order to accomplish this?

Comment: As you've already asked the question modify the previous one to make it clearer.

Comment: "I think I have a short one" is not an appropriate title for a question!

Comment: @Colin, that's what she said.

Comment: Don't worry, you're just looking down on it.

Comment: Search your junk email folder for "pills"

Comment: @joe, seems like a valid sub question to me (ie has nothing to do with his larger card reader issue), it is just phrased really poorly.

Comment: @DanDan:  you owe me a new keyboard.  My old one has coffee all over it now.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it more legit. Note that there is not a "Mysql compact 3.5", what you're seeing is the "Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5", which is entirely different. Basically you need to install a MySQL database connectivity provider for Visual Studio and .NET.

Comment: @Lasse, bravo, the question actually kind of makes sense now.

Comment: Note that I don't consider this a duplicate of his previous question, as the previous question should probably be closed as "not a real question". This one is more to the point and asks a specific question, which can surely be answered.

Comment: ... but it might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101961/sql-connection

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: Note, I think you're seeing the "Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5" provider in your list, and that there is no MySQL provider at all that you can select.

You basically need to install a MySQL provider for .NET that integrates into Visual Studio. There might not be one that integrates into Visual Studio, but you can check this other question here for some information: [how do I connect to mysql database from windows forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101961/sql-connection), which lists some ways to connect to a MySQL database.

Because of this other question that I linked to here, your question might be considered a duplicate, and might be closed.